# Google Chrome extensions that enhance the MMA.SE experience

Tags: discussion

Are there any Google Chrome extensions that enhance the way MMA.SE works or looks?

Answer (score 2):

I was inspired by halirutan's script to build a Google Chrome extension that can replace symbols such as `\[Theta]` with their UTF equivalents.

The extension works by providing a page action. A page action is a little button that sits in the address bar next to the bookmark button and only appears on certain pages, in this case only on MMA.SE. You have to click it for the magic to happen.

To install a Chrome plugin from a 3rd party nowadays you have to first download the plugin to your computer, then open chrome://extensions and then drag and drop the .crx-file onto the browser.

Download here: [MMA.SE symbol converter](http://www.solidfiles.com/d/f36bedbb7c/)

Comment: This is the same as halirutan's extension, right?

Comment: No, halirutan's extension, the one I know of, adds a button to the editor toolbar that can be used to format code in the editor. My extension adds a "page action" button in the address bar of the browser and when you click it, it will replace symbols in posts (not in the editor). So it's a way of doing the replacement without editing the post. Just for viewing purposes.

Comment: Ah, ok. Similar to what Mr.Wizard asked [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/533/5) (but he wanted it to be displayed one way, but copied differently).